# Visual Studio 2012 in a Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, virtual-machine

I need to use Visual Studio 2012, in a windows virtual machine, and to be able to login using Remote Desktop and MULTIPLES sessions access. (Multiple users (very few) can connect to the same time)

I read this is not possible using win8.

What can I do to gain virtualization benefits ?

Thanks in advance. 
Valeria.

Comment: Only Windows Server with the appropriate client access licensing will let multiple users remote desktop to it with Remote Desktop Services.

Comment: It sounds a little crazy to install a win-server to enable a virtual development environment. I was afraid of loosing other good choice...
Ok...and which windows server version do you recommend  ? 
Thanks for your answer.